# Incrementing value in a loop in powershell

Tags: powershell, loops

I would like to ask for some help regarding an incrementing value applied in the script below
For each certificate it found, a counter increments by 1, I tried usig $i=0; $i++ but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
$Expiry = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse
$Rep= @()
 Foreach ($cert in $Expiry)
 {
    if ($cert.notafter -le (get-date).Adddays(120) -AND $cert.notafter -gt (get-date)) 
        {
        
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $Daysleft = $Cert.NotAfter - (get-date)  

            $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Path" $cert.PSParentPath
            $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Issuer" $cert.Issuer
            $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "NotAfter" $cert.NotAfter
            $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "DaysLeft" $Daysleft.Days
            $Rep +=$obj
        }
}
```

My goal here is if it satisfies the condition, it will display the certificate and a counter will be plus 1. until it completes the loop then it displays the total certificates found

Hoping for your help

Thank you

Comment: where in that code did you have $i?

Comment: Then why not use `$Rep.Count` ??

Comment: As aside: [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop counter for this, or even a loop if you use `Select-Object` to return objects with the chosen properties like this:

```
# It's up to you, but personally I would use $today = (Get-Date).Date to set this reference date to midnight
$today  = Get-Date  
$Expiry = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse
$Rep = $Expiry | Where-Object { $_.NotAfter -le $today.AddDays(120) -and $_.NotAfter -gt $today |
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = {$_.PSParentPath}},
                  Issuer, NotAfter,
                  @{Name = 'DaysLeft'; Expression = {($_.NotAfter - $today).Days}}
}

# to know howmany items you now have, use
@($Rep).Count
```

Note:

- I'm using calculated properties in the `Select-Object` line to get the properties you need
- By surrounding `$Rep` in the last line with `@()`, you are forcing the variable to be an array, so you can use its `.Count` property safely